# Are register based machines on von neumann architecture diametrically opposed to functional programming style?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, big-picture

We are so used to von neumann architecture and say a register machine like the x86. (Also with   programming languages built for those machines x86 assembly, C, etc)  Is that approach to computing completely separate from a language and system like haskell?

What would a machine look like that was based functional programming paradigms look like? and  one not running on a register or stack machine.

This article is relevant to my question:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs242/readings/backus.pdf

Comment: This seems too glib to count as an actual answer, but: why wouldn't they look like an x86 running the Haskell environment? Functional programming is a high-level language construct, and the point of high level programming is to insulate you from the messy details of the machine architecture, so why do you think it would be a good idea to remove this insulation? Alternatively, if you really do want both low-level and functional, have you tried looking at combinators?

Comment: Isn't the correct answer to this question simply "No"?

Comment: Yeah, not an actual question.

Comment: If I understand your question, the title has nothing to do with the question.  Please edit it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many hardware designs for executing functional programs have been proposed:

- [The Lisp Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine)
- Steele and Sussman's Scheme [chip design](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359031&coll=portal&dl=ACM)
- The [Reduceron](http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/reduceron/), by Naylor and Runciman

and more (lots are cited in the Reduceron papers).

Answer (score 2):

The abstract machine would look like i.e. the [untyped lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) or the [SKI combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) or just some kind of a [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) dialect.

In hardware it would probably look like a biologic cell, calculating via pattern matching on the genes in the core – directly running that LISP dialect. (You might like to read this blog entry: ["New computer language based on Lisp enables biological modeling"](http://www.thinkgene.com/new-computer-language-based-on-lisp-enables-biological-modeling/))

Comment: Hey, biology has an efficient garbage collector and arbitrary parallelism… you cannot have that on any imperative machine nor any FPGA. And enzymes are nano-bots, so… it might even be able to compile itself on the hardware-level. But bio-computers are still as experimental as quantum-computers.